# Facebook comment count acording to page

Tags: facebook, count, comments, facebook-comments

I have many facebook comment boxes on my website. All pages have separate comment box
i want to display comment count on each page (Only that page comment count)

For that purpose
I have used many possible ways to get facebook comment count according to each page comment box but never succeeded

I used following ways

**Method 1**

```
   <div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://myWebsite.com/" xid="<?=$page_id?>">0</div>
```

**Method 2**

```
   <a class="fb-comments-count" xid="<?=$page_id?>">0</a>
```

**Method 3**

```
   <div class="fb-comments-count" id="comnt-count" data-href="http://myWebsit.com/<?=$page_id?>">0</div>
```

**Method 4**

```
   <div class="fb-comments-count" id="comnt-count" data-href="http://myWebsit.com/?xid=<?=$page_id?>">0</div>
```

**Method 5**

```
   <fb:comments-count xid="<?$page_id?>" href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count>
```

and

```
   <fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/?xid=<?$page_id?>></fb:comments-count>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this simple code

```
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count> Comment
```

you can see at my page www.ayamtube.com

Answer (score 1):

Include the javascript SDK into your page..

```
// Include the facebook SDK (Replace the AppID with your appid)
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The link provided above should work (But it will not validate under a HTML 5 template), use the following link If you have a html 5 template:

`<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"></div>`

Your page probably has 0 comments to start with, so `0` will be displayed inside the div.